# How to open a link in UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

i make an app that shows Bollywood News For that i make `UITableView` and each cell contain Nes and each cell was selected then i want to redirect to `UIWebView` with its link. So how it possible to pass a `URL` to `UIWebView`.

Here My Code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

My Code here :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString *link=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
}
```

Here All Data is Come From `JSON` Data Here dictionary key Value is "link" and each link is Contain each cells relative URLLink i want to open that link in to `UIWebView`.i make for that a `UIWebView` Controller but not know how to pass a link to `UIWebView`

How it is Possible Please Give me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *link=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];

    WebViewController *webView=[[WebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    webview.url = url; // pass URL to webview controller
    [self presentViewController:webView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now in WebViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];        
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```